# General strategy for proving that one interval is a subset of another

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to show that the set $A=\{A_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ where$A_n = (0,4-\frac 1n)$ is an open cover of $B=[2,4)$ -- I'll then show that there is no finite subcover, but one step at a time.  I've shown that $A$ is open.  I'm just wondering what' the general strategy for proving that every point in an interval is contained in another interval.

Would it be fine to show that the supremum of $A$ & $B$ and is $4$ and that $4$ is not a member of either? And then show that the infimum of $A$ is $0$ and the infimum of $B$ is $2$, where $2 \gt 0$.  Would that be fine?  It seems like I should prove that $A$ is an interval (a continuous subset of $\Bbb R$) first.  But then it seems like I need to prove that two continuous subsets of a set are equal iff they have the same inf and sup  and the same max/ min if they contain the max/ min.  And then prove that given two intervals with the same sup but where one has a lower inf, then that one contains the other.

I think I'm overthinking this.  What exactly should I be showing here?

Thanks.

Comment: For some collection to be an open cover, each set in the collection should be open not just their union.

Comment: @Singhal Oh yeah.  You're right.  I've edited the question.

Comment: Since $A$ is the union of open sets, all you need to show is $B\subseteq A$, i.e. every element of $B$ also belongs to $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way:
Let $x\in B$ with $x = 4 - \epsilon$ and $2\ge\epsilon > 0$. Then by the archimedian principle we can find $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac1n < \epsilon$. This means that $0<2\le 4-\epsilon < 4-\frac1n$ so $x\in A_n$, wich shows that $B\subset \bigcup_n A_n$ as claimed.

The strategy here is to exploit the structure of $B$ so that an element of $B$ can be written in a form convenient for finding an $n$ such that $x\in A_n$ (in this case $x=4-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ was the convenient form).